# Parse Alamofire json response

Tags: json, swift, swift3, alamofire

I am trying to parse the response from Alamofire but I can't figure out how to do it.

This is the JSON Response I get (I want to parse out "result") how is this done?

```
JSON: {
    result = 887957;
    status = 0;
}
```

Swift 3

```
if let JSON = response.result.value {
print("JSON: \(JSON)")
}
```

Comment: Please check updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to  specify the type of response is `Dictionary` and then use `subscript` with dictionary to get value of `result`.

```
if let dictionary = response.result.value as? [String: Int] {

    let result = dictionary["result"] ?? 0
    print(result)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String : Any] {
    let result = JSON["result"] as? Int
    let status = JSON["status"] as? Int
    print("Result \(result) Status \(status)")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As per latest **Almofire Lib** and **Swift 3.0** with proper validation:

```
case .success(_):
 if ((response.result.value) != nil) {
  var responseData = JSON(response.result.value!)

  //Userdefaults helps to store session data locally just like sharedpreference in android
  if (response.response ? .statusCode == 200) {
   let result: Int = responseData["result"].int!
   let status: Int = responseData["status"].int!

  } 
 }


case .failure(_):
 print(response.result)
 }
```

Comment: Stop comparing java and ios :-). We will surely discuss it after 10 years as we both know which language have future .Btw I am Java Developer  and swift for fun  :-)

Comment: Feeling like alien in swift world .Hoping will get better with time :-) Thanks for input once again